# Listing the files of remote device through android bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing an application to list out all the remote device file in my android app through bluetooth connectivity.One my devices is paired with the remote device how can i list out all the files from the remote device.And I am trying with OBEX.Is there any easiest way to do that.